# bootstrap CSS: center any col- that overflows a line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

As can be seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5rcs473), I have series of columns that are nested in a single row and designed to overflow onto as many new lines as necessary.

Since each `col-*` has the property `align: left;` from Bootstrap, cols that overflow onto a new line stay left aligned.

Visually, I'd like to have "incomplete" lines have `div`s that are centered, like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiperific/58m7cyrv). But, these `col-` divs are created dynamically, so I can't just use `offset`s or additional `row`s to fix.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy. First, you change your HTML and add some special class just to make sure you don't affect the columns in other places of your layout. Since you have `app-style`, let's use that for the row, and let's add the `myCentre` class name to the `xs-4` columns. Like this:

```
<div class="row app-style">
    <div class="col-xs-4 myCentre">
        <div class="box-btn-reports">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 myCentre">
        <div class="box-btn-reports">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 myCentre">
        <div class="box-btn-reports">
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 myCentre">
        <div class="box-btn-reports">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row app-style">
    <div class="col-xs-4 myCentre">
        <div class="box-btn-reports">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 myCentre">
        <div class="box-btn-reports">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 myCentre">
        <div class="box-btn-reports">
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 myCentre">
        <div class="box-btn-reports">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 myCentre">
        <div class="box-btn-reports">
            <p>Another col just because I can</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, we can use some extremely simple CSS. Basically, we're removing Bootstrap styles to use old school responsive approach: `text-align:center` for container, `text-align:left` for item elements, nothing new:

```
.app-style{text-align:center;}
.myCentre{display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
    margin-right:-4px; 
    vertical-align:top;}
.box-btn-reports {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: .5em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #888888;
    border-radius: 8px;}
  p {
    padding: .1em;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 150%;
  }
```

and now you can [[see the fiddle here]](http://jsfiddle.net/qtgvtup5/) and how those columns are happily centered[1](http://jsfiddle.net/qtgvtup5/)

Comment: Thanks! I would have never thought of this.